# How to sum with two variables involving date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I get raw data much similar to the example below that has thousands of rows.  What I need to be able to do is sum the values in column C (Or column D) based on the value in column A within the date ranges in column B.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click `Insert` -> `Pivot Table` -> Tick `Date_TY`, `PropDemTY`, `PropRevTV` in sequence -> Drag `STR#` to `Column` above `Date_TY`, the settings should like this... (don't have English excel installed, just match the position is ok)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for subtotals

[image]

will turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

which can also be collapsed to show only totals by clicking the number 2 on the left
[image]